# WCF Client Exception: error while trying to deserialize parameter

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting this error when I try to call a WCF Service:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the 
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter 
>   [http://tempuri.org/:ResultValue](http://tempuri.org/%3aResultValue). The InnerException message was 'Error 
>   in line 1 position 1741. Element 
>   'htp://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:anyType' 
>   contains data from a type that maps to the name 
>   'htp://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataAccess:Person'. 
>   The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. 
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 
>   'Person' to the list of known types - for example, by using the 
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types 
>   passed to DataContractSerializer.'.

I have a Interfaces project with the following definitions:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IPersonExtended : IPerson
{
    // If I remove the List of IPerson property, it works fine
    List<IPerson> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

I have a DataAccess project that implements the interfaces:

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonExtended : IPersonExtended
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private List<IPerson> mContacts = new List<IPerson>();

    // If I remove the List of IPerson property, it works fine
    public List<IPerson> Contacts
    {
        get { return mContacts; }
        set { mContacts = value; }
    }
}
```

My Service Contract looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Person))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(PersonExtended))]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ServiceCallResult<GetPeopleResponse> GetPeople(GetPeopleRequest request);
}
```

My Service looks like:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public ServiceCallResult<GetPeopleResponse> GetPeople(GetPeopleRequest request)
    {
        GetPeopleResponse response = new GetPeopleResponse();
        // Get Some people that have contacts
        response.People = GetPeopleFromSomewhere();

       ServiceCallResult<GetPeopleResponse> result = 
           new ServiceCallResponse<GetPeopleResponse> { ResultValue = response };

       return result;
    }
 }
```

And my response object looks like:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(PersonExtended))]
[KnownType(typeof(Person))]
[KnownType(List<Person>))]
[KnownType(List<PersonExtended))]
public class GetPeopleResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<PersonExtended> People { get; set; }
}
```

The Response object is just wrapped in a `MessageContract` object that contains status information, etc.

**EDIT**
If I remove the Contact (List) property through the entire workflow, it works fine.  I'm wondering if it is related to trying to use a property with a list to an interface instead of a concrete object, but I'm not sure how to get around that with my project structure without adding a circular reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` on the `Person` class

```
[DataContract]
public class Person : IPerson
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`KnownTypeAttribute` is supposed to enable you to designate acceptable derived class for a given `DataContract`. It specifies types that should be recognised by the `DataContractSerializer` when **Serializing** or **Deserializing** a given type.

`GetPeopleResponse` does not derive from `Person` or `PersonExtended`...

Also there is a lot of stuff in your code that doesn't make sense at all to me...
Here is something that makes sense to me...

```
public interface IPerson {
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IPersonExtended : IPerson {
    List<IPerson> Contacts { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Person : IPerson {
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class PersonExtended : Person, IPersonExtended {
    [DataMember]
    public List<Person> Contacts { get; set; }

    public PersonExtended() {
        Contacts = new List<Person>();
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService {
    [OperationContract]
    IList<PersonExtended> GetAllPeople();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private IList<PersonExtended> _people;

    public MyService() {
        _people = new IList<PersonExtended>();
    }

    public IList<PersonExtended> GetAllPeople() {
        return _people
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite it.  I've updated my question.  This represents a simplified version of my proprietary object.  The `ServiceCallResult` object is just a wrapper that contains status, etc. information.

Comment: you have a return statement at the end of your service class which tells me you don't know what your are doing... the service class also does not implement the function declared by the interface.

Comment: Actually, it's not that I don't know what I am doing.  It was a simple cut/paste issue.  I obviously just left out the line with function def, which needs to be there to satisfy the interface.

Comment: Why do you send in request as a parameter when it is not used for anything? you could just define the function like this in the interface to satisfy your needs `ServiceCallResult<GetPeopleResponse> GetPeople();` And for heaven and god sake try and add the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes on the `People` and `PeopleExtended` classes.

Comment: Again, this is a simplified version - the request parameter generally contains filter information, etc.  And I did add the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes to the DataAccess classes to no avail.  As shown in the edit above, if I remove the `Contacts` property that is a `List<IPerson>` from the extended object, it works fine.

Comment: change from `IList<IPerson>` to `IList<Person>` Interfaces can not be serialized, in my examples i return `T` as `class`

Comment: I was able to get past this by removing the `IList<IPerson>` from the `IPersonExtended` interface, and just adding a property to the `PersonExtended` class.  I included the `Person` object as a `KnownType`, and it comes across as expected.

Comment: Good to hear @TheCheezInside :) best of luck further.